# Groovy built-in REST/HTTP client?

Tags: rest, groovy, httpbuilder

I heard that Groovy has a built-in REST/HTTP client. The only library I can find is [HttpBuilder](https://github.com/jgritman/httpbuilder), **is this it?**

Basically I'm looking for a way to do HTTP GETs from inside Groovy code without having to import any libraries (if at all possible). But since this module doesn't appear to be a part of core Groovy I'm not sure if I have the right lib here.

Comment: To summarize the below answers `j = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(new URL("https://httpbin.org/get").getText())` then
`println j.headers["User-Agent"]`

Comment: You might also checkout an updated (re)version of the HttpBuilder library - https://http-builder-ng.github.io/http-builder-ng/

Comment: If you use `@Grab` it makes http-builder fairly painless to use: `@Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', module='http-builder', version='0.7')`

Answer (score 180):

Native Groovy GET and POST

```
// GET
def get = new URL("https://httpbin.org/get").openConnection();
def getRC = get.getResponseCode();
println(getRC);
if (getRC.equals(200)) {
    println(get.getInputStream().getText());
}

// POST
def post = new URL("https://httpbin.org/post").openConnection();
def message = '{"message":"this is a message"}'
post.setRequestMethod("POST")
post.setDoOutput(true)
post.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json")
post.getOutputStream().write(message.getBytes("UTF-8"));
def postRC = post.getResponseCode();
println(postRC);
if (postRC.equals(200)) {
    println(post.getInputStream().getText());
}
```

Comment: How do you set headers on GET or POST calls with this?

Comment: @DLeh The setRequestProperty method does that.  I used it in the example to set the Content-Type header.  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setRequestProperty-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-

Comment: In pipeline as code, you must do it in shared library otherwise jenkins will forbid it for security reasons, Overriding them is possible but then you may really add vulnerabilities.

Comment: How to get the response headers? I can't find it out .

Comment: @luxin.chen figure it out: `post.getHeaderFields()`, see more methods in http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/sun/net/www/protocol/https/HttpsURLConnectionImpl.html#getHeaderFields

Comment: At what exact point is the HTTP Request actually sent? Sometime during `post.getResponseCode();` ?

Comment: @PhilippDoerner The request is implicitly sent by `getResponseCode()` or any similar method that depends on the connection being connected. I believe you can also call `connect()` to explicitly send the request. 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html

Comment: @JimPerris Could it be that `post.getOutputStream().write(message.getBytes("UTF-8"));` also counts among those that implicitly send a request? I just encountered a bug where I set a request header after writing the body with that statement and it threw an error of "already connected", which was fixed by moving the writing of the body after the writing of the headers

Comment: @PhilippDoerner sure, that could be the case. I haven't messed with Groovy or Java in a couple years, so kinda rusty on this stuff.

Comment: `URL.getOpenConnection` returns an `URLConnection`. But `URLConnection` does not know the method `setRequestMethod`, because only `HttpURLConnection` (a child of `URLConnection`) knows the method. If I try this in [ScriptRunner](https://docs.adaptavist.com/sr4js/latest), I get a type error: `Cannot find matching method java.net.URLConnection#setRequestMethod(java.lang.String)`.

Answer (score 69):

If your needs are simple and you want to avoid adding additional dependencies you may be able to use the `getText()` methods that Groovy adds to the `java.net.URL` class:

```
new URL("http://stackoverflow.com").getText()

// or

new URL("http://stackoverflow.com")
        .getText(connectTimeout: 5000, 
                readTimeout: 10000, 
                useCaches: true, 
                allowUserInteraction: false, 
                requestProperties: ['Connection': 'close'])
```

If you are expecting binary data back there is also similar functionality provided by the `newInputStream()` methods.

Comment: How about a post request?

Answer (score 40):

The simplest one got to be:

```
def html = "http://google.com".toURL().text
```

Comment: Brillient idea. what can I do if we need add proxy server name and port?

Comment: proxy settings are controlled by the containing JVM as described [in the oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html).

Answer (score 33):

You can take advantage of Groovy features like with(), improvements to URLConnection, and simplified getters/setters:

**GET:**

```
String getResult = new URL('http://mytestsite/bloop').text
```

**POST:**

```
String postResult
((HttpURLConnection)new URL('http://mytestsite/bloop').openConnection()).with({
    requestMethod = 'POST'
    doOutput = true
    setRequestProperty('Content-Type', '...') // Set your content type.
    outputStream.withPrintWriter({printWriter ->
        printWriter.write('...') // Your post data. Could also use withWriter() if you don't want to write a String.
    })
    // Can check 'responseCode' here if you like.
    postResult = inputStream.text // Using 'inputStream.text' because 'content' will throw an exception when empty.
})
```

Note, the POST will start when you try to read a value from the HttpURLConnection, such as `responseCode`, `inputStream.text`, or `getHeaderField('...')`.

Comment: Voted up for the 'note' that was the key. Thanks

Comment: This looks very simple. What's with exception handling and ressource handling? Is there no `close()` and `disconnect()` necessary for the open connection? Is there a simple way to pass the content of a file through the http post outputstream?

Answer (score 14):

[HTTPBuilder](https://github.com/jgritman/httpbuilder/wiki) is it. Very easy to use.

```
import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder

def http = new HTTPBuilder('https://google.com')
def html = http.get(path : '/search', query : [q:'waffles'])
```

It is especially useful if you need error handling and generally more functionality than just fetching content with GET.

Comment: Thanks @Dakota Brown - and can you confirm I don't need to import anything?

Comment: That's the downside, you'll need the jar: http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/download.html. Nothing in groovy core for it.

Comment: Thanks @Dakota Brown - please see my comment underneath Will P's answer - I have the same question for you

Comment: http://grails.org/plugin/rest will allow you to use HTTP Builder in GRAILS project

Comment: I downvoted because in 2020 this isn't working well. [http-builder](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder/http-builder/0.7.1) hasn't been updated since 2014, and it uses a [JSON library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.json-lib/json-lib/2.4) that hasn't been updated since 2010 and isn't actually on Maven central anymore (try downloading the JAR: you'll get a 404).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think http-builder is a Groovy module, but rather an external API on top of [apache http-client](https://hc.apache.org/) so you do need to import classes and download a bunch of APIs. You are better using Gradle or `@Grab` to download the jar and dependencies:

```
@Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', module='http-builder', version='0.7.1' )
import groovyx.net.http.*
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.*
import static groovyx.net.http.Method.*
```

Note: since the CodeHaus site went down, you can find the JAR at (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder/http-builder)

Comment: I don't know grails enough to answer and i don't think it belongs to the view, neither. You'd probably better downloading the dependencies or using `URL` as per @John's answer

Comment: @smeeb the `@Grab` would be added in the `grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy`.  Then it would be working within controllers, services, ... -- but please don't add such code to the view.

Answer (score -2):

```
import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder;

public class HttpclassgetrRoles {
     static void main(String[] args){
         def baseUrl = new URL('http://test.city.com/api/Cirtxyz/GetUser')

         HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) baseUrl.openConnection();
         connection.addRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json")
         connection.with {
           doOutput = true
           requestMethod = 'GET'
           println content.text
         }

     }
}
```