# Simple HTTP GET request in groovy

Tags: http, groovy

I am very newbie for this groovy programming. I have written an API which is running in my local system (`localhost:2100`).

Now i want to make a simple GET request to this API using groovy code. I searched a lot for this but i cant find the clear guidance.

I tried for this :

http://www.kellyrob99.com/blog/2013/02/10/groovy-and-http/
http://rest.elkstein.org/2008/02/using-rest-in-groovy.html  etc.. But nothing works.

Also i came across `HttpBuilder`. I cant get clear idea of this. Please share your ideas.

EDIT:

I tried for this:

```
def client = new RESTClient("http://localhost:2100");
def res = client.get(path:"xxx/yyy/zzz")
```

I am receiving error:

```
Groovy:unable to resolve class RESTClient
```

Whether I need to add dependency in my pom.xml?

Comment: @Opal see my edited post..

Comment: dupe/similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25692515/groovy-built-in-rest-http-client

Answer (score 21):

If you need to do a simple GET petition. You can use the [URL](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/net/URL.html) Class.
For example, to get the content of example.org, with a GET request

```
new URL("http://example.org/").text
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder;

public class HttpclassgetrRoles {
     static void main(String[] args){

         def baseUrl = new URL('http://test.xyz.com/api/state/GetUser')
         HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) baseUrl.openConnection();
         connection.addRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json")
         connection.with {
           doOutput = true
           requestMethod = 'GET'
           println content.text
         }

     }
}
```

It is  definitely worked for me

Answer (score 0):

[`RESTClient`](http://javadox.com/org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder/http-builder/0.6/groovyx/net/http/RESTClient.html) class is not a part of a standard groovy library. You not only need an appropriate [maven](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder%22%20AND%20a%3A%22http-builder%22) entry but you need to import (via `import` statement in the script) appropriate classes you need to use.

[Here](https://github.com/jgritman/httpbuilder/wiki)'s a wiki site for HTTPBuilder.

Comment: Actually i added that repository in maven POM.xml . SO the above problem is solved. but HTTP request is coming into my API layer.

Comment: @Subburaj, if the problem is solved and my answer was helpful please accept and upvote it.