# How can I perform HTTP POST requests from within a Jenkins Groovy script?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-workflow

I need to be able to create simple HTTP POST request during our [Jenkins Pipeline](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin) builds. However I cannot use a simple curl sh script as I need it to work on Windows and Linux nodes, and I don't wish to enforce more tooling installs on nodes if I can avoid it.

The Groovy library in use in the Pipeline plugin we're using should be perfect for this task. There is an extension available for Groovy to perform simple POSTs called [http-builder](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder/http-builder/0.7.1), but I can't for the life of me work out how to make use of it in Jenkins' Groovy installation.

If I try to use Grapes Grab to use it within a Pipeline script I get an error failing to do so, [as seen here](https://gist.github.com/strich/38e472eac507bc73e785).

```
@Grapes(
    @Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', module='http-builder', version='0.7.1')
)
```

Maybe Grapes Grab isn't supported in the bundled version of Groovy Jenkins uses. Is it possible to simply download and add http-builder and its dependencies to the Jenkins Groovy installation that goes out to the nodes?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25692515/groovy-built-in-rest-http-client

Comment: Sadly not - This has more to do with how Jenkins integrates with it. Its not as simple as that. :/

Comment: I thought you need brackets - @Grapes([  @Grab(...)   ])

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but why not just use standard java libraries that are already on the jenkins classpath?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader
import java.io.InputStreamReader
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter
import java.net.URL
import java.net.URLConnection

def sendPostRequest(urlString, paramString) {
    def url = new URL(urlString)
    def conn = url.openConnection()
    conn.setDoOutput(true)
    def writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream())

    writer.write(paramString)
    writer.flush()
    String line
    def reader = new BufferedReader(new     InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()))
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
      println line
    }
    writer.close()
    reader.close()
}

sendPostRequest("http://www.something.com", "param1=abc&param2=def")
```

Comment: Because Script Security Plugin don't allow to call URL.openConnection() method

Answer (score 46):

For the Jenkin's Pipeline I would recommend installing the ["HTTP-Request" plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTTP+Request+Plugin)

It is nicely integrated in groovy so you can use it like this:

```
def response = httpRequest "http://httpbin.org/response-headers?param1=${param1}"
```

Comment: Quite important limitation: it doesn't allow to add header programmatically.

Comment: It does: ``httpRequest customHeaders: [[name: 'FOO', value: 'BAR']], url: 'http://company.com'``

Comment: For security’ sake, be aware that: _"Every execution will log all parameters. Be careful to not pass private information such as passwords or personal information"_ (quoting official doc)

Comment: Hi there, Do you happen to know how to send https request through httprequest plugin in jenkins pipeline, Since the certificate is private, so my https request will be blocked by certification error, are there any parameters as curl command has like -k?? Thanks!