# API POST request to Proxmox with params using Groovy Script in Jenkins

Tags: api, authentication, jenkins, post, groovy

I am trying to obtain an authentication ticket using a POST request with 3 parameters(user,pass,realm) to access Proxmox API Server to be parsed for further queries.

As I am writing the code in Groovy Script for a parameter in a Jenkins job, I am not getting much help in terms of errors. I have tried the POST request on insomnia and it has no problems.

I am still very new to GroovyScript any pointers in the right direction is much appreciated.

```
def url = new URL("https://$HOST/api2/json/access/ticket")

def connection =  url.openConnection()
connection.setDoOutput(true)
connection.setRequestMethod("POST")
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json")
connection.setRequestProperty('Username', '$USER')
connection.setRequestProperty('Password', '$PASS')
connection.setRequestProperty('Realm', '$REALM')
def requestCode = connection.getResponseCode
```

Comment: use try-catch `try {  ...your code here... } catch(e) { display error here }` to catch and display error. also you could install groovy on your local computer and try to run your script

Comment: I've got my code now on GroovyConsole, and I am getting a javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed error, i've tried saving the cert using keytools however still no luck(The cert at the https website appears to be invalid)

Comment: that's another question )) to work with certificate could be complicated especially if it's a first time for you. try to search `java/groovy trust all` to trust all certificates...

Comment: Thanks, searching that helped me disable the SSL to further help me troubleshoot. Furthermore, I dont think I am passing the parameters right, I currently tried to do it this way:def url = new URL("https://$HOST/api2/json/access/ticket?username=$USER&password=$PASS&realm=$REALM") Is this correct?

Comment: Ask the developers of your API How to pass the auth parameters.

Comment: Answer found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36115872/how-can-i-perform-http-post-requests-from-within-a-jenkins-groovy-script.

Comment: Not need connection.setRequestProperty('Realm', '$REALM'), using Username@realm

Answer (score 0):

Not need `connection.setRequestProperty('Realm', '$REALM')`, using `Username@realm`
try this, write to [API](https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Proxmox_VE_API):

```
def url = new URL("https://$HOST/api2/json/access/ticket")
def connection =  url.openConnection()
connection.setDoOutput(true)
connection.setRequestMethod("POST")
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json")
connection.setRequestProperty('Password', '$PASS')
connection.setRequestProperty('Username', '$USER' + '@' + '$REALM')
def requestCode = connection.getResponseCode
```