# Jenkins Pipeline - getting java.io.NotSerializableException with sh and curl

Tags: curl, jenkins, groovy, jira, jenkins-pipeline

I'm creating a jenkins pipeline which creates a Jira Ticket at some point.
Unfortunately I'm getting: `java.io.NotSerializableException: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.EncodingGroovyMethods$1`

Code:

```
    token = createEncodedToken()

    def curlCommand = "curl -H 'Authorization: Basic ${token}' -X POST -d \'${payload}\' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' ${jira_url} > JIRA_TICKET"

    try {
        println "executing: ${curlCommand}"
        sh "${curlCommand}"
    } catch (NotSerializableException err) {
        println "${err}"
    }
```

createEncodedToken:

```
def createEncodedToken() {
   def auth = "${jira_user}:${jira_password}"
   return auth.bytes.encodeBase64()
}
```

The resulting curlCommand works! I can send it in curl or in a sample pipeline. But as soon as I use it in my jira.groovy script I get the exception.

```
[Pipeline] echo
executing: curl -H "Authorization: Basic MYTOKEN=" -X POST -d "{"fields":{"project":{"key":"KEY"},"summary":"Pipeline Test","description":"Creating of an issue using project keys and issue type names using the REST API","issuetype":{"name":"Story"}}}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://MYJIRA/rest/api/2/issue/ > JIRA_TICKET
[Pipeline] sh
[plinetest] Running shell script
[Pipeline] echo
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.EncodingGroovyMethods$1
```

The output file JIRA_TICKET is used to read the resulting issue-key.

Fun fact: although I get an exception, the ticket is created... but I can't read the JIRA_TICKET file.

I'm currently testing it in a Sandbox Pipeline:

```
def jira = fileLoader.fromGit('jira.groovy', 'MYBITBUCKET-pipeline.git', 'master', 'CREDS', '')
echo "create ticket"
def payload = '{"fields":{"project":{"key":"KEY"},"summary":"Pipeline  Test","description":"Creating of an issue using project keys and issue type names using the REST API","issuetype":{"name":"Story"}}}'
jira.createTicket(payload)
```

The call is tested and works fine. Maybe the jira lib causes the problem?
I'm aware of the Serializable concept of jenkins pipeline, but I don't get what I miss.
I'm pretty clueless right now... Any help is appreciated.

Comment: May be this link can help you: https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/204972960-The-pipeline-even-if-successful-ends-with-java-io-NotSerializableException

Comment: It doesn't :( I moved the curl execution to a separate method and annotated it with @NonCPS. Still the same error.

Comment: What is the code inside `createEncodedToken()`? I bet it causes the issue.

Comment: Added the createEncodedToken code

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score 3):

`encodeBase64()` does not return a string. It returns a class which implements `groovy.lang.Writeable`, which has a `toString()` method.

You need to call toString() explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use
`new URL(jira_url).openConnection();` instead of curl. You can refer to this
[Groovy built-in REST/HTTP client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25692515/groovy-built-in-rest-http-client)