# How to do a POST request with JSON via Groovy?

Tags: rest, curl, groovy

I have one REST API, which expects data. We are using following curl command for sending data and header information:

```
curl -X "POST" "https://xxx.xxx.xxx/xapplication/xwebhook/xxxx-xxxx" -d "Hello, This is data"
```

What will be the equivalent Groovy Script?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Following thread solved my issues http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25692515/groovy-built-in-rest-http-client

Answer (score 6):

Although for a simple `GET` you could use plain Groovy:

```
'https://xxx.xxx.xxx/xapplication/xwebhook/xxxx-xxxx'.toURL().text
```

However that doesn't give you much flexibility (different http verbs, content-type negociation...etc). Instead I would use [HttpBuilder-NG](https://http-builder-ng.github.io/http-builder-ng/index.html) which is a very complete library and it's built having Groovy syntax in mind.

Regarding a working JSON example, the following sends a JSON body in a `POST` request and parses back the response, which will be available as a traversable map:

```
@Grab('io.github.http-builder-ng:http-builder-ng-okhttp:0.14.2')
import static groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson
import static groovyx.net.http.HttpBuilder.configure

def posts = configure {
    request.uri = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com'
    request.uri.path = '/posts' 
    request.contentType = 'application/json'
    request.body = toJson(title: 'food', body: 'bar', userId: 1)
}.post()

assert posts.title == 'foo'
```

Comment: The HttpBuilder-NG seems to be dormant as of October 2020.

Comment: @sodastream 6 months later still dormant.