# How to pass the credential to login to Jenkins from groovy script?

Tags: json, authentication, jenkins, groovy

I am trying access one of the Jenkins job's log using groovy script. but getting 403 error. How do I pass the credential to login in below code?

```
def jsonStr1 = new URL(myEnvUrl+"warnings40Result/api/json?pretty=true").getText()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting HTTP 403 which stands for Unauthorized attempt.

Possibly there is a login page of Jenkins, you should include it to access your next page. page. Have a check following link:

[Groovy built-in REST/HTTP client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25692515/groovy-built-in-rest-http-client)

Comment: Still not able to access without configure Login Credentials into the groovy code **def jsonStr1 = new URL(myEnvUrl+"warnings40Result/api/json?pretty=true").getText()** 

I tried all the solution of url:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25692515/groovy-built-in-rest-http-client)

Anyone having idea how to parse this by passing credential’s .

Comment: Can you share your code about logging in to Jenkins? What have you did so far?

Comment: **My code:**    def  warningJsonUrl = EnvBuildUrl+"warnings40Result/api/json?token=4eca462899e426937a94006a20561011"
    
    def authString = "admin1:admin1".getBytes().encodeBase64().toString()
    
    def conn = warningJsonUrl.toURL().openConnection()
    conn.setRequestProperty( "Authorization", "Basic ${authString}" )
    if( conn.responseCode == 200 ) {
    println("code:"+conn.responseCode)
    
    def textJsonObj = new JsonSlurper().parseText(conn.content.text) 
    }
    how i will parse as text?

Comment: @user1671258 what is output of following codes? println(conn.content) and println(conn.content.text)

Answer (score 0):

```
def jsonStr1 = new URL(myEnvUrl+"warnings40Result/api/json?pretty=true").getText()

I tried all the solution of url:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25692515/groovy-built-in-rest-http-client

i think without Login Credentials code we can't access 'jsonStr1'. so i tried below code, now i am able to access but while parsing the value its giving error: 

code:200
[PostBuildScript] - Problem occurred: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog. 


my code:
def  warningJsonUrl = EnvBuildUrl+"warnings40Result/api/json?token=4eca462899e426937a94006a20561011"

def authString = "admin1:admin1".getBytes().encodeBase64().toString()

def conn = warningJsonUrl.toURL().openConnection()
conn.setRequestProperty( "Authorization", "Basic ${authString}" )
if( conn.responseCode == 200 ) {
println("code:"+conn.responseCode)

def textJsonObj = new JsonSlurper().parseText(conn.content.text) 
}
how i will parse as text?
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please consider formatting your post as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). It'll help people help you.