# Jenkins create Folder with REST API in groovy script

Tags: rest, jenkins, groovy, directory

i am trying to create a Folder in Jenkins using a groovy script. For that i use an REST API call.
My starting point is was basically a curl command:

```
curl -XPOST "http://userName:YourApiToken@JenkinsURL:Port/createItem?name=FolderName&mode=com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.Folder" -H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

I got this from https://gist.github.com/marshyski/abaa1ccbcee5b15db92c and found later out that it also works if you put the user into the URL. Using this line in the Windows cmd works perfectly and generates me a new Folder in my Jenkins.

Now i try to do the same thing but from a groovy script. For that i use the following code:

```
import groovyx.net.http.*

def post = new URL("http://userName:YourApiToken@JenkinsURL:Port/createItem?name=FolderName&mode=com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.Folder").openConnection();
post.setRequestMethod("POST")
post.setDoOutput(true)
post.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
def postRC = post.getResponseCode();
println(postRC);
if(postRC.equals(200)) {
    println(post.getInputStream().getText());
}
```

I got this basically from [Groovy built-in REST/HTTP client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25692515/groovy-built-in-rest-http-client/42664926) (i have heard apache Http is deprecated)

Long story short i did not manage to create a folder with the given groovy script. I always get an **403 response** (I run the script from windows cmd and inside jenkins with the script console).

I also played around with Jenkins-crumb but that seems not necessary because the above cmd command already worked.

So the question is does anyone know what i am missing? why is the groovy script not working but the curl command is?
Or has anyone a different approach on how to generate a Folder in Jenkins from a groovy script?

Edit:
When i try to run the curl command in the groovy script with .execute() i get an "The system cannot find the file specified" Error.

```
String command = "curl -XPOST "+ '"http://user.name:ApiToken@JenkinsURL:8080/createItem?name=FolderName&mode=com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.Folder"'+ ' -H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded"'
println(command)
command.execute()
```

Answer (score 0):

`curl` command not present on windows platform - so you have

> "The system cannot find the file specified".

403 - forbidden. something wrong with auth I guess.

better to move user&pass to header:

```
post.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic ${"username:password".bytes.encodeBase64().toString()}")
```

Comment: I was able to make the curl command in groovy work. I had curl installed (its just a folder not really installation) but i forgot to set the PATH in the environment variables. (i guess the curl worked before because i opened the cmd over a network drive which probably already knew the curl command). I am still not able to make the Groovy version work (without curl). I assume Jenkins denies the request directly because of something (without checking if authentication is right or wrong).