# Validate authentication and create accesstoken and use same to access another url in groovy

Tags: groovy

my Requirement is to validate login credentials against a url and will receive access token in response and use same access token to access another url and will get output string.
All the coding i need to done in groovy.
Please help.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25692515/groovy-built-in-rest-http-client may be able to get you started