# Jenkins/Groovy: Why does withCredentials() introduce a NotSerializableException exception?

Tags: rest, jenkins, serialization, groovy

This question is a follow-up to [Groovy/Jenkins: how to refactor sh(script:"curl ...") to URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69458227/groovy-jenkins-how-to-refactor-shscriptcurl-to-url).

Though I intend to try invoking REST API with `HTTP Request` - as the one answerer has suggested - I'd like to also specifically learn about/understand the original problem RE: non-serializability.

I've reduced the code in the linked Q&A to more minimally demonstrate the problem.
This code:

```
@Library('my-sandbox-libs@dev') sandbox_lib

pipeline {
  agent any

  stages {
    stage( "1" ) { steps { script { echo "hello" } } }

    stage( "2" ) {
      steps {
        script {
          try {
            my_lib.v4()
          }
          catch(Exception e) {
            echo "Jenkinsfile: ${e.toString()}"
            throw e
          }
        }
      }
    }

    stage( "3" ) { steps { script { echo "world" } } }
  }
}
```

```
// vars/my_lib.groovy
import groovy.json.JsonOutput
def v4() {
  def post = new URL("https://bitbucket.company.com/rest/build-status/1.0/commits/86c36485c0cbf956a62cbc1c370f1f3eecc8665d").openConnection();
  def dict = [:]
  dict.state = "INPROGRESS"
  dict.key = "foo_42"
  dict.url = "http://url/to/nowhere"
  def message = JsonOutput.toJson(dict).toString()
  post.setRequestMethod("POST")
  post.setDoOutput(true)
  post.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json")
  post.getOutputStream().write(message.getBytes("UTF-8"));
  def postRC = post.getResponseCode();
  println(postRC);
  if (postRC.equals(200)) {
      println(post.getInputStream().getText());
  }
}
```

...generates HTTP error 401. This is expected, because it invokes a Bitbucket REST API without necessary authentication.

What's missing is the "Bearer: xyz" secret-text. In the past, I've gotten this secret-text using Jenkins'/Groovy's `withCredentials` function, as in the modified function `v4()` below:

```
// vars/my_lib.groovy
import groovy.json.JsonOutput
def v4() {
  def post = new URL("https://bitbucket.company.com/rest/build-status/1.0/commits/86c36485c0cbf956a62cbc1c370f1f3eecc8665d").openConnection();
  def dict = [:]
  dict.state = "INPROGRESS"
  dict.key = "foo_42"
  dict.url = "http://url/to/nowhere"
  def message = JsonOutput.toJson(dict).toString()
  post.setRequestMethod("POST")
  post.setDoOutput(true)
  post.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json")
  withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'bitbucket_cred_id',
                          variable: 'auth_token')]) {
    post.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + auth_token)
  }
  post.getOutputStream().write(message.getBytes("UTF-8"));
  def postRC = post.getResponseCode();
  println(postRC);
  if (postRC.equals(200)) {
      println(post.getInputStream().getText());
  }
}
```

...but I've discovered that the addition of that `withCredentials`-block, specifically, introduces a `java.io.NotSerializableException: sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl` runtime exception.

At the linked Stack Overflow Q&A, one commenter has informed me that the problem has to do with serializable vs. non-serializable objects in this function. But I'm having a hard time understanding what non-serializable object is introduced by use of the `withCredentials`-block.

As a point of reference, use of the same `withCredentials`-block works just fine when I invoke the same REST API using `curl` instead of "native" Jenkins/Groovy functions. I.e. the following code works fine:

```
def v1() {
  def dict = [:]
  dict.state = "INPROGRESS"
  dict.key = "foo_42"
  dict.url = "http://url/to/nowhere"
  withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'bitbucket_cred_id',
                          variable: 'auth_token')]) {
    def cmd = "curl -f -L " +
              "-H \"Authorization: Bearer ${auth_token}\" " +
              "-H \"Content-Type:application/json\" " +
              "-X POST https://bitbucket.company.com/rest/build-status/1.0/commits/86c36485c0cbf956a62cbc1c370f1f3eecc8665d " +
              "-d \'${JsonOutput.toJson(dict)}\'"
    sh(script: cmd, returnStatus: true)
  }
}
```

So, in summary, this question is **why does `withCredentials()` introduce non-serializable objects (and what is the non-serializable object), which causes `NonSerializableException` exceptions with use of `URL` and/or `HttpURLConnection`, and does one work around this?**

I'm not unwilling to use a different solution, such as `httpRequest` objects, but this question is about learning the nature of this specific problem, and how to work around it with the existing objects, i.e. `URL` and `HttpURLConnection` objects.

---

**Update**: As it turns out, I'm unable to use the suggested alternate solution using `httpRequest` objects, because the `HTTP Request` plugin is only available to Jenkins versions 2.222.4 or newer, which our Jenkins does not meet. It's outside my privilege to update our Jenkins version, and basically I'll need to assume an inability to upgrade Jenkins.

Our Jenkins version is 2.190.3, which has Groovy version 2.4.12.

Comment: @zett42 - in this case, is the `withCredentials()` the item that you would consider the "low level" code that calls down to Groovy/Java API? Or if not, which bits of code are? Sorry, my familiarity with Jenkins/Groovy is _very_ rudimentary: even such things as what is considered "low level" are not obvious to me yet.

Comment: I've turned my comment into an answer. Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

When having such issues I usually try to put the "low level" code that calls down to Groovy/Java API, into `@NonCPS` functions. Objects in such functions don't need to be serializable, so we can freely use any Groovy/Java API.

Background reading: [Pipeline CPS Method Mismatches](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/cps-method-mismatches/)

Make sure you **don't call any Jenkins pipeline steps from `@NonCPS` functions** (nor any other function that is not marked `@NonCPS`) - such code could silently fail or do unexpected stuff! (There are some "safe" functions like `echo` though.)

As `withCredentials` is a pipeline step, it has to be called from a "regular" function (not marked as `@NonCPS`), one level up the call chain.

Note that I'm passing `auth_token` as an argument to `v4_internal`. If you need other Jenkins variables in the code, these should also be passed as arguments.

```
// vars/my_lib.groovy
import groovy.json.JsonOutput

def v4() {
  withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'bitbucket_cred_id',
                          variable: 'auth_token')]) {
    v4_internal(auth_token)
  }
}

@NonCPS
def v4_internal( def auth_token ) {
  def post = new URL("https://bitbucket.company.com/rest/build-status/1.0/commits/86c36485c0cbf956a62cbc1c370f1f3eecc8665d").openConnection();
  def dict = [:]
  dict.state = "INPROGRESS"
  dict.key = "foo_42"
  dict.url = "http://url/to/nowhere"
  def message = JsonOutput.toJson(dict).toString()
  post.setRequestMethod("POST")
  post.setDoOutput(true)
  post.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json")
  post.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + auth_token)
  post.getOutputStream().write(message.getBytes("UTF-8"));
  def postRC = post.getResponseCode();
  println(postRC);
  if (postRC.equals(200)) {
      println(post.getInputStream().getText());
  }
}
```

Comment: I wonder if you could expand on your answer a little bit RE: this concept of `@NonCPS` code and non-`@CPS` code? I have a primarily `C`/`C++`  background, and this concept of "classes" of functions that have different "capability/restrictions" is very strange to me. Still in the process of trying to grok this Jenkins/Groovy concept.

Comment: @StoneThrow Jenkins transforms our Groovy scripts to make it possible to pause/resume the pipeline. Unfortunately this requires all objects to be serializable (and has other restrictions too). By using `@NonCPS` you can selectively disable this transformation. [See more](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/cps-method-mismatches/).

Answer (score 0):

This sucks - and I hope someone comes along with a better answer - but it looks like the only way I can pull this off is as follows:

```
@Library('my-sandbox-libs@dev') sandbox_lib

pipeline {
  agent any

  stages {
    stage( "1" ) { steps { script { echo "hello" } } }

    stage( "2" ) {
      steps {
        script {
          try {
            my_lib.v5(my_lib.getBitbucketCred())
          }
          catch(Exception e) {
            echo "Jenkinsfile: ${e.toString()}"
            throw e
          }
        }
      }
    }

    stage( "3" ) { steps { script { echo "world" } } }
  }
}
```

```
// vars/my_lib.groovy
import groovy.json.JsonOutput
def getBitbucketCred() {
  withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'bitbucket_cred_id',
                          variable: 'auth_token')]) {
    return auth_token
  }
}

def v5(auth_token) {
  def post = new URL("https://bitbucket.company.com/rest/build-status/1.0/commits/86c36485c0cbf956a62cbc1c370f1f3eecc8665d").openConnection();
  def dict = [:]
  dict.state = "INPROGRESS"
  dict.key = "foo_42"
  dict.url = "http://url/to/nowhere"
  def message = JsonOutput.toJson(dict).toString()
  post.setRequestMethod("POST")
  post.setDoOutput(true)
  post.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json")
  req.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + auth_token)
  post.getOutputStream().write(message.getBytes("UTF-8"));
  def postRC = post.getResponseCode();
  println(postRC);
  if (postRC.equals(200)) {
      println(post.getInputStream().getText());
  }
}
```

Specifically, I ***must*** invoke `withCredentials()` completely separate from the scope of the function that uses `URL` and/or `HttpURLConnection`.

I don't know if this is considered acceptable in Jenkins/Groovy, but I'm dissatisfied by the inability to call `withCredentials()` from the `v5()` function itself. I'm also unable to call a `withCredentials()`-wrapper function from `v5()`.

When I was trying to call `withCredentials()` either directly in `v5()` or from a wrapper function called by `v5()`, I tried every combination of `@NonCPS` between `v5()` and the wrapper function, and that didn't work. I also tried explicitly setting the `URL` and `HttpURLConnection` objects to `null` before the end of the function (as suggested at [Jenkins/Groovy: Why does withCredentials() introduce a NotSerializableException exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69484244/jenkins-groovy-why-does-withcredentials-introduce-a-notserializableexception)), and neither did that work.

I'd be disappointed in Jenkins/Groovy if this is the only solution. This feels like an artificial limit on how one can choose to organize his code.

---

**Updating with more detail in response to @daggett:**

RE: calling `withCredentials()` directly from `my_lib.v5()` or calling it from a wrapper function, let's start with `mylib.groovy` set up as follows (let me also take the opportunity to give the functions better names):

```
def withCredWrapper() {
  withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'bitbucket_cred_id',
                          variable: 'auth_token')]) {
    return auth_token
  }
}

def callRestFunc() {
  def post = new URL("https://bitbucket.company.com/rest/build-status/1.0/commits/86c36485c0cbf956a62cbc1c370f1f3eecc8665d").openConnection();
  def dict = [:]
  dict.state = "INPROGRESS"
  dict.key = "foo_42"
  dict.url = "http://url/to/nowhere"
  def message = JsonOutput.toJson(dict).toString()
  post.setRequestMethod("POST")
  post.setDoOutput(true)
  post.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json")

  // version 1:
  withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'bb_auth_bearer_token_cred_id',
                          variable: 'auth_token')]) {
    post.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + auth_token)
  }
  // version 2:
  //post.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + withCredWrapper())

  post.getOutputStream().write(message.getBytes("UTF-8"));
  def postRC = post.getResponseCode();
  println(postRC);
  if (postRC.equals(200)) {
      println(post.getInputStream().getText());
  }
}
```

With the above code, function `callRestFunc()` can either call `withCredentials()` directly, as above, or indirectly by the wrapper function `withCredWrapper()`, i.e.:

```
...
  // version 1:
  //withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'bb_auth_bearer_token_cred_id',
  //                        variable: 'auth_token')]) {
  //  post.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + auth_token)
  //}
  // version 2:
  post.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + withCredWrapper())
...
```

Further, `@NonCPS` can be applied to one of `withCredWrapper()` or `callRestFunc()`, both, or neither.

Below are the specific failures with all 8 combinations thereof:

1.

```
def withCredWrapper() {
  ...
}

def callRestFunc() {
...
  // version 1:
  withCredentials(...)
  ...
}
```

**Failure:** `Jenkinsfile: java.io.NotSerializableException: sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl`

2.

```
def withCredWrapper() {
  ...
}

@NonCPS
def callRestFunc() {
...
  // version 1:
  withCredentials(...)
  ...
}
```

**Failure:** `expected to call my_lib.callRestFunc but wound up catching withCredentials; see: https://jenkins.io/redirect/pipeline-cps-method-mismatches/ Masking supported pattern matches of $auth_token`, `Jenkinsfile: java.io.NotSerializableException: sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl`

3.

```
@NonCPS
def withCredWrapper() {
  ...
}

def callRestFunc() {
...
  // version 1:
  withCredentials(...)
  ...
}
```

**Failure:** `Jenkinsfile: java.io.NotSerializableException: sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl`

4.

```
@NonCPS
def withCredWrapper() {
  ...
}

@NonCPS
def callRestFunc() {
...
  // version 1:
  withCredentials(...)
  ...
}
```

**Failure:** `expected to call my_lib.callRestFunc but wound up catching withCredentials; see: https://jenkins.io/redirect/pipeline-cps-method-mismatches/ Masking supported pattern matches of $auth_token`, `Jenkinsfile: java.io.NotSerializableException: sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl`

5.

```
def withCredWrapper() {
  ...
}

def callRestFunc() {
...
  // version 2:
  post.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + withCredWrapper())
  ...
}
```

**Failure:** `Jenkinsfile: java.io.NotSerializableException: sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl`

6.

```
def withCredWrapper() {
  ...
}

@NonCPS
def callRestFunc() {
...
  // version 2:
  post.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + withCredWrapper())
  ...
}
```

**Failure:** `expected to call my_lib.callRestFunc but wound up catching my_lib.withCredWrapper; see: https://jenkins.io/redirect/pipeline-cps-method-mismatches/`

7.

```
@NonCPS
def withCredWrapper() {
  ...
}

def callRestFunc() {
...
  // version 2:
  post.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + withCredWrapper())
  ...
}
```

**Failure:** `expected to call my_lib.withCredWrapper but wound up catching withCredentials; see: https://jenkins.io/redirect/pipeline-cps-method-mismatches/ Masking supported pattern matches of $auth_token`, `Jenkinsfile: java.io.NotSerializableException: sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl`

8.

```
@NonCPS
def withCredWrapper() {
  ...
}

@NonCPS
def callRestFunc() {
...
  // version 2:
  post.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + withCredWrapper())
  ...
}
```

**Failure:** `expected to call my_lib.callRestFunc but wound up catching withCredentials; see: https://jenkins.io/redirect/pipeline-cps-method-mismatches/`

Comment: could you give more info what happens when you apply @noncsp for v5 and call it within withcredentials ? `didn't work` means nothing.

Comment: @daggett - updated the answer with enumeration of all the failure combinations of `@NonCPS` placement and calling `withCredentials()` directly or from a wrapper function. Hope that is sufficient info.

Comment: to continue with v5 you have `not serializable HttpsURLConnectionImpl` you should wrap whole URL staff into function with @NonCPS - you can't have connection (`post` variable in your code) outside @NonCPS.