Not able to run CURL in Jenkins Active choice parameter
I am trying to get my Active choice parameter drop down options from curl response.
Below is the code i pasted in Active choice parameter
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'cred-id', usernameVariable: 'username', passwordVariable: 'var')]) {
    try {
        if (appname == 'app1') {
            def process = "curl -u $USERNAME:$PASSWORD -X GET 'https://<app url>/api/v1/repos/<repo path>/tags?pageSize=10&count=false&includeManifests=false' -H 'accept: application/json' -H 'X-Csrf-Token: <token>' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'".execute()
            process.waitFor()
            def output = process.in.text.trim()
            def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
            def object = jsonSlurper.parseText(output)

            def option_list = object*.name
            return option_list
        } else {
            return ["aminelse"]
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return[e]
    }
}

after saving if i click on build with parameter the options am getting is like below
[object Object]

Any suggestions were greatly appreciated.
Let us know what we are missing.
Edit1:
Tried the below as per the native curl method.
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import java.net.HttpURLConnection

withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'creds-id', usernameVariable: 'CREDENTIALS')]) {
    try {
        def credentials = CREDENTIALS.split(":")
        def username = credentials[0]
        def password = credentials[1]
        
        if (appname == 'app1') {
            def url = new URL("<url>/?pageSize=10&count=false&includeManifests=false")
            def connection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET")
            connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + "${username}:${password}".bytes.encodeBase64().toString())
            connection.setRequestProperty("accept", "application/json")
            connection.setRequestProperty("X-Csrf-Token", "<token>")
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json")

            def output = connection.inputStream.text.trim()
            def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
            def object = jsonSlurper.parseText(output)
            def option_list = object*.name
            //println(option_list)
            return option_list

        } else {
            return ["aminelse"]
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return[e]
    }
}

got not response in parameter drop down.

Since you're using groovy, why not use the native Groovy GET: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42664926/3730626

Tried that, My parameter option is blank now. Not printing "else part" also if i choose other options. Not sure what is wrong.

@ramesh If you have new insights, please [edit] the question and add what you have tried, and how it failed.

@cfrick, updated now. if you are aware kindly let me know the proper way to perform curl operation in groovy under Active choice parameter. i will try with that. I am not sure what is missing part in my script.
