jmeter : how to launch asynch http(s) requests inside a while controller
I have a number of 'n' http(s) requests to be run in asynch way.
The number 'n' depends by dynamic output of a previous http request in jmeter project.
So I need to run those 'n' http(s) requests in a while controller.
The problem is that the requests are serialized and launched in sequence inside the while controller, that is: when the request 'i' is completed, then the 'i+1' request is launched , up to when i<n
Instead, my need is to run the requests in asynch mode (background &), I need to run the request 'i+1' before that the request 'i' is completed.
How can I do this with a jmeter while (or other loop controller) ?
I know that bzm - Parallel controller could allow, but it needs a specific set number of requests nested in the controller, and in my case it's not possible because the number 'n' of requests is dynamic.
How could solve this?
Thanks
I tried while controller inside bzm Parallel controller, but the solution doesn't work

You can use JSR223 Sampler for creating parallel HTTP requests dynamically. The response time will be the longest request execution time.
If you need to track response time for each request individually - you can use SampleResult.addSubResult() function.
More information:

Groovy built-in REST/HTTP client?
How to Send Groovy HTTP and HTTPS Requests


The two  alias reported under "More information" are pointing to the same link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25692515/groovy-built-in-rest-http-client
That is ok? Or they should be two different links?
